# Run rate calculate in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE data 
    (
        Event_Date date,
        approved int, 
        rejected int
    )
    
    INSERT INTO data (Event_date, approved, rejected)
    VALUES
        ('20190910', '5', '2'),
        ('20190911', '6', '3'),
        ('20190912', '5', '2'),
        ('20190913', '7', '5'),
        ('20190914', '8', '4'),
        ('20190915', '10', '2'),
        ('20190916', '4', '1')
```

How to make a loop or something else for calculate run rate  and get results(in Rolling monthly rate CL I write how formula need to be use)  like this:

```
Event_date   approved,      rejected    Rolling monthly rate
------------------------------------------------------------
20190901           5           2           ---
20190902           6           3           6+5/5+6+2+3
20190903           4           2           6+4/6+3+4+2
20190903           7           5           7+4/4+2+7+5
20190904           8           4           8+4/7+5+8+4
20190905           10          2           ....
20190906           4           1           .....
```

Comment: Hi @Snaigius, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would help if you could also add the progress so far, what was tried so far?

Comment: Could you tell on the basis of what certain numbers are used, I can’t see the pattern

Comment: @HarveyDent used approved and rejected numbers.
20190901 date we cant calculate  Rolling rate because we don't have info before.
But logic are we need sum approved today + before one day and divine (/) by sum of today approved + rejected + approved one day before + rejected one day before

Comment: @EduardUta `TO_CHAR(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN resolution = 'APPROVED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS DECIMAL(7,2)) /(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN resolution = 'APPROVED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS DECIMAL(7,2)) + CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN resolution = 'REJECTED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS DECIMAL(7,2))),'999D999') AS "rate"
`
but this is wrong because script calculate only today, but how write loop as I have described, I do not know

Comment: Ok, thanks! You can also edit the question and add that (what you tried already) to the end of the text, will surely help the next person that will help on this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lag()` function, which returns the previous value, is perfect for this task.
You need to write a `case when` statement and skip the first entry since there is no previous value and then calculate using the desired formula.

```
select *, case when row_number() over() > 1
          then  approved + lag(approved) over() / approved + rejected + lag(approved)  over() + lag(rejected)  over()
          end   as rate
from my_table
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5897649c4cacff8ed378be5eaaf7d36e)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oops, mixed up, I needed the `lag` function, thanks)

Comment: But `log()`  didn't for logarithm? because in your fiddle where date are 20190911 you get 10.38, but calculated by hands (6+5)/(6+5+3+2) I get 0.68

Comment: @Snaigius I changed the answer, i mixed up the `log()` and `lag()` functions, try again)

Comment: Hmm but how you get 16 :? (6+5)/(6+5+3+2) = 0.68

Comment: in your code need add some brackets and its works fine